# How to deal with "Random HTTP GET" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get, http-get

I need to send multiple get requests(required) one by one. When the count is 2-3, it works fine, but with almost 6 HTTP Get requests, sometimes some of them fails and give `Internal Sever Error(500)`. Opening the error link in new tab gives required results.

So there is nothing wrong from server side.

I'm facing this problem both in : `localhost` and `production`.
How to deal with this situation from client side?

I've tried:

1. `NodeJS + SocketIO` to send data from server without asking. [with so much data if socket keeps writing till 60 sec. socket re-registers & restarts from beginning.]
2. `Angular + NGResource`. [internally uses http get. issue persists.]
3. `Angular + Restangular Lib`. [internally uses http get. issue persists.]

Please suggest how do I know what the problem is. Then only I can think of a solution.

Thnx!!

Comment: Maybe your server does not allow 6 concurrent connections to the same client...

Comment: If this was the case... It'd never allow it.
Problem is: It works sometimes and sometimes 1 req. fails, sometimes 3 fail...

Comment: Fix the server. Sounds like it's broken.

Comment: Server's problem? I don't think so. What's the clue?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function in which you can wrap your HTTP calls. It will repeat the call until it passes. Beware! If the HTTP call fails 100% of the time (for example, malformed URL), then the function will not stop (In testing, the function was called >70,000 times. Apparently there is no recursion limit with promises). For that case, I've included a limited version of the function that stops after n attempts.

```
var persistentRequest = function(requestFn) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  requestFn().then(function() {
    deferred.resolve();
  }, function() {
    persistentRequest(requestFn).then(
      function() {
        deferred.resolve();
      }
    );
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}

var persistentRequestLimited = function(requestFn, n) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  if (n <= 0) {
    deferred.reject('Did not complete in given number of tries');
  } else {
    requestFn().then(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    }, function() {
      persistentRequestLimited(requestFn, n-1).then(
        function(data) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        function(rejection) {
          deferred.reject(rejection);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

For example, use it like:

```
persistentRequest(function() {
  return $http.get('/myurl');
});

persistentRequestLimited(function() {
  return $http.get('/myurl');
}, 10);
```

Don't forget to inject $q into your controller/service/etc.

Comment: Answer seems good. I tried something like this. on error of HTTP get I iterated request for 'n' no. of times. I'd be glad if i could find the reason of this problem occurring rather than finding a solution.
Could you please help me in finding that too.

Comment: Do you run the server? I agree with Adam Batkin that it sounds like a server problem, given that you can repeat the request and it works.

Comment: Yes! I'm running the server. Well, it says: 500(Internal Server Error) so might be Adam's point is hitting the nerve. But how do I know what's broken. 
Detail: It's a rails server dealing with a simple scaffold.